# Python comparison function based on generator acts weird

Tags: python

I've made a small function to check elements of string if they are in corresponding sublist of the list.

```
def pin_sequence_checker(pin, filter):
    """We get pin and filter list,
    function checks if all pin digits are in corresponding sublist.
     i.e. pin = 123, list = [[123], [456], [789]] ==> False
     pin = 147, list = [[123], [456], [789]] ==> True"""
    return [d in "".join(filter[i]) for d in pin for i in range(len(filter)) if pin.index(d) == i]


print(pin_sequence_checker("255", [['263'], ['5936'], ['869']]))
```

However:

If we run it for, let's say "247" it will return ==> [True, False, False]

If i run "222" ==> [True, True, True]

Seems that if we hit a digit once - it will return True for it regardless if its in corresponding sublist or not.

Another example:
"155" ==> [False, True, True]

Can someone kindly help me to understand what's going on? I'm pretty new to Python so can't get it yet. Thanks !!

P.S. removed all() from return for troubleshooting.

Comment: What is the desired output for the examples with `247` `255` `222` etc?

Comment: 247 should be True, False, False
255 should be True, True, False
222 should be True, False, False

Comment: And every time it is checked against [[123], [456], [789]], right?

Comment: yes, however the last if  ( pin.index(d) == i ) should narrow comparison so the 0 symbol of string should only be looked for in 0 sublist, 1st symbol in 1st sublist, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly this should work for you:

```
def pin_sequence_checker(pin, filter_):
    """We get pin and filter list,
    function checks if all pin digits are in corresponding sublist.
     i.e. pin = 123, list = [[123], [456], [789]] ==> False
     pin = 147, list = [[123], [456], [789]] ==> True"""
    
    result = []
    for ix, number in enumerate(pin):
        result.append(number in filter_[ix][0])
        
    return result


print(pin_sequence_checker("222", [['263'], ['5936'], ['869']]))
>>> [True, False, False]
```

Comment: @Piosipov You can try this and tell me if it works for you. PS: Don't use python built-in names for variables (e.g. `filter`, `str`, `id`, etc) https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Comment: yes i know that :) just sometimes i do, but usually fix that pretty fast when code go crazy.

Regarding your solution:

If i run it for "269" it returns [True, False, True], should be [True, True, True]

Comment: However I've found one error of mine reading your code:

It works that way 

all([d in "".join(f[i]) for ix, d in enumerate(pin) for i in range(len(f)) if ix == i])

since i used .index() and when we run similar digits - it points to the same index each time, which is not cool

Comment: @Piosipov > If i run it for "269" it returns [True, False, True], should be [True, True, True]. With this "`0 symbol of string should only be looked for in 0 sublist, 1st symbol in 1st sublist, and so on`" in mind it shouldn't or...?

Comment: Sorry, i dont get you :)
The idea was : we take 0 symbol, look if it is in 0 sublist, we take 1 symbol, look for it in 1 sublist and so on